# How to deal/handle with this error when use nconf function in IMSL library?

Tags: fortran, numerical-methods, imsl

I used the function `nconf` in IMSL library to solve a *constrained nonlinear optimization problem*. I simplified the problem to describe the error occurred.

The objective function is `log(x1 * x2 - x3 ^ 2)`. The constrain is `x1 * x2 - x3 ^ 2 > 0`. The fortran code is as followed.

```
program main
use IMSL

integer IBTYPE, IPRINT, M, MAXITN, ME, N
parameter (IBTYPE = 0, IPRINT = 0, M = 1, MAXITN = 100, ME = 0, N = 3)

real FVALUE, X(N), XGUESS(N), XLB(N), XSCALE(N), XUB(N)
external FCN
data XGUESS/10.0E0, 10.0E0, 2.0E0/, XSCALE/3*1.0E0/
data XLB/1.0E-6, 1.0E-6, 1E-6/, XUB/50, 50, 50/
!open(44, file = "test.txt", status = "unknown")
call NCONF(FCN, M, ME, N, XGUESS, IBTYPE, XLB, XUB, XSCALE, IPRINT, MAXITN, X, FVALUE)
!write(*, *) X
end program

subroutine FCN(M, ME, N, X, ACTIVE, F, G)
integer M, ME, N
real X(3), F, G(*)
logical ACTIVE(*)
ACTIVE(1) = .TRUE.

!write(44, *) x 

F = log(x(1) * x(2) - x(3) ** 2) 

!write(44, *) F

IF(ACTIVE(1)) G(1) = X(1) * x(2) - x(3) ** 2
return
end subroutine
```

When I ran the code, the constraint doesn't work.  `nconf` do search a `(x1, x2, x3)` that makes `x1 * x2 - x3 ^ 2 < 0`, but **then the program throw an exception**.`x1 * x2 - x3 ^ 2` is in the `log` function . It can't be negative. If the constrain works, `x1 * x2 - x3 ^ 2` should not be negative.
I don't know how the nconf function search point x and how the constrain works.

Comment: Please share the exception as well so that others can help you.

Comment: you need to gracefully handle the case when the solver tries to violate the constraint.

Answer (score 1):

elaborating on my comment, the only way the solver learns what the constraints are is by going 'out of bounds' , so you should very much expect out of bounds values and handle them gracefully.

A typical way to do this is:

```
G(1) = X(1) * x(2) - x(3) ** 2
if(g(1).gt.0)then
    f=log(g(1))
else
    f=-10.e30 
endif
```

It may not matter what you return in the out of bounds case but check the docs for the imsl routine to see if it says something about that.

just by the way, note since you hard coded `active(1)=.true.` there is no need for the `if(active(1))..` construct.

Comment: Thank you. I use IMSL 4.0. The docs don't say much about the "out of bound " case. Actually the answer of the example in IMSL docs is slightly "out of bound". I tried your method for both my real problem and the simple one, but programs threw " ERROR 2 from DNCONF.  The line search used  more than 5
 function calls, therefore it has been declared unsuccessful." I don't know how `ACTIVE` works, I just try different ways.

Comment: that is a different error which relates to your basic problem formulation. Your example makes no sense as an optimization problem, but I assume that's not your real problem either.  In any case the main point here is the calling routine does not "see" the functional form of the constraint, all it does is pass in values to test, so inevitably it will pass in invalid values and you need to handle that.